Would this be a metaphor?
So there is an incident where someone was vacationing in Scotland. This other person asks her if she is in Scotland. The one vacationing says "yes". The person's response is "Take as much of the land as you can with you." The one vacationing ends up removing a stone from an ancient burial sites. When outraged people ask her about it her response is that this other woman told her to. The woman meant to take it with her eyes & ears. To take in the scenery and take photographs of the land and historical places. Not to actually bend over and pick up a rock from the grounds & take it back to the U.S!
What form of speech would that be? I thought there was an actual term for that. Not just figuratively. I don't think that it is a metaphor or idiom. Help?

It's the physical-representing-the-notional (specifically here the taking of such)
                                                    (taking a solid memento, the vehicle,
used to convey
                                                retaining a lasting impression, the tenor)                                                          
                        
                            primary metaphor.                                         [see Nordquist]
Other examples within this primary metaphor:

'He drank in the scenery.'

'Mila Kunis absolutely devoured the scenery when she played the Wicked Witch of the West...'. [Reddit]

'England's In My Heart' [Archie Marvellous song]


Arguably, as take's primary meaning involves the physical (and photos are now usually stored digitally),
'Take nothing but photographs'
involves this metaphor.

The phenomenon you described sounds to me like a fairly convoluted metonymy or synecdoche. You know, the ol' part for the whole, or whole for the part.
You can "take" something literally or figuratively. The vacationer "took" a physical object home with her, literally. She should have taken as much of Scotland home with her as her mind could hold, figuratively. In other words, the other person you speak of is telling the vacationer to store up her memories purposefully so she can keep them alive long after her vacation ends.
The vacationer grasped and took a small rock home with her. That's the "part." She may have failed to take into her stored memories the highlights of the land and the people of the land. That's the "whole."
